Where did Jesus perform the “Feeding of the 4,000"?
Matthew 15:29-39 NKJV

29 Jesus departed from there, skirted the Sea of Galilee, and went up
on the mountain and sat down there. 30 Then great multitudes came to
Him, having with them the lame, blind, mute, maimed, and many
others; and they laid them down at Jesus’ feet, and He healed them. 31
So the multitude marveled when they saw the mute speaking, the
maimed made whole, the lame walking, and the blind seeing; and they
glorified the God of Israel.
32 Now Jesus called His disciples to Himself
and said, “I have compassion on the multitude, because they have now
continued with Me three days and have nothing to eat. And I do not
want to send them away hungry, lest they faint on the way.”
33 Then His disciples said to Him, “Where could we get enough bread in
the wilderness to fill such a great multitude?”
34 Jesus said to them, “How many loaves do you have?”
And they said, “Seven, and a few little fish.”
35 So He commanded the multitude to sit down on the ground. 36 And He
took the seven loaves and the fish and gave thanks, broke them and
gave them to His disciples; and the disciples gave to the multitude.
37 So they all ate and were filled, and they took up seven large
baskets full of the fragments that were left. 38 Now those who ate
were four thousand men, besides women and children. 39 And He sent
away the multitude, got into the boat, and came to the region of
Magdala.

Also, Mark 8:1-9. Verses 9 and 10 say:

9 There were about 4000 men who ate. After they ate, Jesus told them
to go home. 10 Then he went in a boat with his followers to the area
of Dalmanutha.

It seems like Jesus skirted the Sea of Galilee, and went up on the mountain.
He then went to the area of Dalmanutha, concluding with him leaving by boat.
Do we know where the feeding of the 4000 actually took place?



Similar




Where did the feeding of the 5000 occur?


Where is Dalmanutha?




Seems like there's an implicit assumption here that the feeding of the 5k is a distinct event from the 4k, and I'm not sure that's been conclusive in the literature on this subject https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/83582/why-are-there-2-variants-of-feeding-of-the-multitude-in-mark-and-matthew

Preliminary point: Some suggest that the feeding of the 5000 and the 4000 are the same incident.  However, it is clear from Matthew and Mark's account that the two are distinct incidents for the following reasons:

both are recorded within two chapters; 5000 in Matt 14 and 4000 in Matt 15
Jesus teaches an important lesson based on the comparison and contrast between these two incidents (and how much He started with and was left over) in Matt 16:5-12.

Location
Both incidents of mass feeding occurred close to the Sea of Galilee.  The precise location for each is not recorded except to suggest that both had a lot of grass and was on a mountain slope; both were fairly isolated.  The western side of the Sea of Galilee is relatively flat, but the eastern side is quite hilly.
The closest we get to the location is for the 4000 is the significant preposition, "para" in the phrase, "Jesus went along the sea of Galilee". The construction suggests that Jesus traveled around the shoreline of the coast of the sea because "para" means "beside" or "alongside".
Just before, Jesus is recorded as being in the region of Tyre and Sidon, Matt 16:21, which is north-west of the sea of Galilee.  In V29, Jesus departed from there and travelled "para" to the sea of Galilee, suggesting he arrived at the sea in (say) Capernaum or Bethsaida and then travelled further around the lake in a clockwise direction to find an isolated place on a mountainside.
The conclusion that Jesus was somewhere near the eastern shore of Galilee (on the mountainside) is confirmed by the fact that after feeding the 4000, He got into a boat and travelled (Matt 15:39) to the western shore to arrive at Magdala/Magadan.
More than this we cannot say.

Even saying this much is going farther than I would like to go, as I am among those who am not convinced that the feeding of the 5k was a historically distinct event from the feeding of the 4k! To paraphrase: "We are told, but I do not know."

I see. As for Magdala/Magadan. I couldn't find an image with the location on a map. Where would that be near?

@Jason_ See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magdala - just north of Tiberias.

Yes, agreed. Well stated. Up-voted +1. To say that the feeding of the five thousand and the four thousand is the same event is, to my mind, a negative assessment of the faithful reporting of the evangelists.

Mark reports a location missing in Matthew. Following Jesus's healing of the Canaanite woman's child, Mark 7:31 reports that Jesus departed from the vicinity of Tyre, passed through Sidon, proceeded down to the the Sea of Galilee and into the region of the Decapolis.

As depicted on the map, Jesus departed from the vicinity of Tyre, travelled north to Sidon, then retraced southward to the Sea of Galilee, entering the region of the Decapolis, highlighted in yellow. The term "Decapolis" originates from Greek, meaning "Ten Cities", signifying a cluster of Gentile, Hellenistic urban centers. Among these, Hippos is the only major city along the coast of the Sea of Galilee. While there is no concrete evidence that the feeding of four thousands happened here, considering the size of the crowd, it is plausible that the event occurred in proximity to Hippos.

Thank you. Maps are always good visual aids. Now I'm wondering where Magdala/Magadan is.

This is another question. But you may try in biblewalks.com if you satisfied the information. https://www.biblewalks.com/Magdala/
